# angualrjs : ajax crawling(by using ruby on rails)

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3.2, web-crawler

I am trying to make and angularjs site crawlable.I am using Ruby On Rails as a server side language.

I have read many article about ajax crawling and i understood that to make site crawl-able we need to provide html snapshot.I am using ruby on rails to provide html snapshot.whenever the request comes with param'S as "_escape_frgament_=" I provides dynamically generated html snapshot by using ruby on rails.

I need to know is this a right approach to make angularjs crawlable by using ruby on rails??.

Comment: yes it is. it doesn't what kind of backend your are using.

Comment: @Michael : Thanks, now i can confidently implement it....